# CodeIgniter not recognizing SMTP Address

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I have an weird problem and don't know how to fix it. My code looks exactly right but system tries to connect my own server(localhost of server) instead of the right SMTP address.

Here is my code:

```
    $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
    $config['smtp_host'] = "smtp.mandrillapp.com";
    $config['smtp_port'] = "587";
    $config['smtp_user'] = "my@mailaddress.com"; 
    $config['smtp_pass'] = "mypassword";
    $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
    $config['mailtype'] = "html";
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
    $CI -> email -> initialize($config);


    $CI -> email -> from('mail@address');
    $CI -> email -> reply_to('mail@address');
    $CI -> email -> to($email);
    $CI -> email -> subject('Some Topic');
    $CI -> email -> message('Some message');
    $CI -> email -> send();
```

When I run this script, I get this response:

```
    220-server.mydomain.com ESMTP Exim 4.86 #2 Sun, 08 Nov 2015 11:31:39 +0000 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail. 
hello: 250-server.mydomain.com Hello li1430-121.members.linode.com [85.90.227.125]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-STARTTLS
250 HELP
```

So, it get's login error 'cause it's trying to connect wrong server. I made a research on web but couldn't find any solutions about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are completely wrong. It means way you use email library code is not correct.

1. You can't load like this `$CI ->`
2. No Spaces between methods `$CI -> email ->`

Correct code is like this

```
$config['protocol'] = "smtp";
$config['smtp_host'] = "smtp.mandrillapp.com";
$config['smtp_port'] = "587";
$config['smtp_user'] = "my@mailaddress.com"; 
$config['smtp_pass'] = "mypassword";
$config['charset'] = "utf-8";
$config['mailtype'] = "html";
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$this->email->initialize($config);


$this->email->from('mail@address');
$this->email->reply_to('mail@address');
$this->email->to($email);
$this->email->subject('Some Topic');
$this->email->message('Some message');
$this->email->send();
```

[Email Class in CI](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html)

Comment: I'm using this code in a helper, so I can not use $this, I have to use $CI. Also this is not a solution for my problem, I tried to use your structure in a model but the result is same.